# How to find start(min) and end(max) date in xml file?

Tags: xslt

I have an XML file. I should find for same field2 start(min) date and End(max) date from field3. Maybe xsl have some function to find it.Because I try do it trying to find min month and min day and max month, max day.
XML:

```
<document>
    <line id="0">
        <field id="2">X111</field>
        <field id="3">2011-03-31</field>
    </line>
    <line id="1">
        <field id="2">X111</field>
        <field id="3">2011-04-04</field>
    </line>
    <line id="2">
        <field id="2">X111</field>
        <field id="3">2011-04-02</field>
    </line>
    <line id="3">
        <field id="2">X222</field>
        <field id="3">2011-04-04</field>
    </line>
    <line id="4">
        <field id="2">X222</field>
        <field id="3">2011-04-01</field>
    </line>
    <line id="4">
        <field id="2">X333</field>
        <field id="3">2011-04-01</field>
    </line>
</document>
```

Output:

```
<document>
<Message>
    <ID>X111</ID>
    <dateStart>2011-03-31</dateStart>
    <dateEnd>2011-04-04</dateEnd>
</Message>
<Message>
    <ID>X222</ID>
    <dateStart>2011-04-01</dateStart>
    <dateEnd>2011-04-04</dateEnd>
</Message>
<Message>
    <ID>X333</ID>
    <dateStart>2011-04-01</dateStart>
    <dateEnd>2011-04-01</dateEnd>
</Message>
</document>
```

Please help to solve it. I'm working with stylesheet version="1.0".

Comment: Could you post your XSLT code?

Comment: @Antonio Pérez: I didn't manage it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can probably be optimized but it returns the requested results:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="test" match="line" use="field[@id=2]"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <document>
            <xsl:for-each select="//line[generate-id()=generate-id(key('test',field[@id=2]))]">
                <xsl:sort select="field[@id=2]"/>
                <Message>
                    <ID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="field[@id=2]"/>
                    </ID>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('test',field[@id=2])">
                        <xsl:sort select="field[@id=3]"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </Message>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </document>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="line">
        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <dateStart>
                <xsl:value-of select="field[@id=3]"/>
            </dateStart>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
            <dateEnd>
                <xsl:value-of select="field[@id=3]"/>
            </dateEnd>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

I upvoted @mousio's answer, but I'd prefer to see the first of each `line` type handled in its own template. So, in the spirit of TMTOWTDI, here's how I would have done it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <xsl:key name="byField2" match="line" use="field[@id=2]" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <document>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document/line" />
        </document>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="line[count(.|key('byField2', field[@id=2])[1])=1]">
        <Message>
            <ID><xsl:value-of select="field[@id=2]" /></ID>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('byField2', field[@id=2])" mode="m">
                <xsl:sort select="field[@id=3]" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </Message>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="line" mode="m">
        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <dateStart><xsl:value-of select="field[@id=3]" /></dateStart>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
            <dateEnd><xsl:value-of select="field[@id=3]" /></dateEnd>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="line" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I think this is easier to read (and probably more efficient on large documents, since it doesn't abuse `//`).

Comment: +1 for eliminating the for-each and providing a better key name than `test` (did I really post that?) :]

Comment: I like the pull style for brevity, but I think matching common ancestor and using push style is more semantic because it's closer to XSLT 2.0 grouping and remember us that unless we add the ancestor reference to the key value we would be grouping by **any level**.

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation shows how to find the wanted minimum and maximum**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="line">
       <xsl:sort select="field[@id=3]"/>
     </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="line">
  <xsl:if test="position()=1">
   Earliest:
   <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
   Latest:
   <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<document>
    <line id="0">
        <field id="2">X111</field>
        <field id="3">2011-03-31</field>
    </line>
    <line id="1">
        <field id="2">X111</field>
        <field id="3">2011-04-04</field>
    </line>
    <line id="2">
        <field id="2">X111</field>
        <field id="3">2011-04-02</field>
    </line>
    <line id="3">
        <field id="2">X222</field>
        <field id="3">2011-04-04</field>
    </line>
    <line id="4">
        <field id="2">X222</field>
        <field id="3">2011-04-01</field>
    </line>
    <line id="4">
        <field id="2">X333</field>
        <field id="3">2011-04-01</field>
    </line>
</document>
```

**produces**:

```
   Earliest:
   <line id="0">
   <field id="2">X111</field>
   <field id="3">2011-03-31</field>
</line>
   Latest:
   <line id="3">
   <field id="2">X222</field>
   <field id="3">2011-04-04</field>
</line>
```

**Explanation**:

Choosing the first and last element from the sorted node-list. The dates are in a "good" format, so they are sorted just as strings.

Comment: Your results are quite different from the *wanted, correct result*.

Comment: @mousio: Yes, I am addressing the main question of the OP: " I should find for same field2 start(min) date and End(max) date from field3". It is not even clear from the question that the provided "Output" is the desired output...

Comment: You are entirely correct, my apologies. The OP's question should be worded better, and I should be more careful with reading between the lines and just making assumptions…

Comment: The OPs desired output seems pretty clear to me: group by `field[@id=2]` and then find the earliest and latest dates in each group's `field[@id=3]`. In other words, multiple max/min are desired.

Comment: @mosio, @lwburk: I decided to answer the OP's main question. Why should we always do everithing for them up to the last detail? It is good for them to do at least part of the work. I was assuming that the OP knows how to do the rest -- that he only needed the min/max for dates piece worked out.